# Find which gain the process will be unstable?

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control, linear-control

I have a transfer function:

$$G(s) =\frac{num(s)}{den(s)}$$

And if I want to simulate this transfer function with a P-controller. I need to do a feedback transfer function:

$$G_f(s) =\frac{KG(s)}{1 + KG(s)} = \frac{\frac{Knum(s)}{den(s)}}{\frac{Knum(s)+den(s)}{den(s)}} = \frac{Knum(s)}{Knum(s)+den(s)}$$

I want to find the $K \in \Re$ who gives the process unstable dynamics.
To do that, I need to find the poles from:
$$ 0 =  Knum(s)+den(s)$$

Assume that $num(s)$ and $den(s)$ are arbitrary polynomial row vectors.

**And now the question:**

Is there a analytical solution to this or only numerical?

Can I sett the poles to $s_p > 0$  e.g $s_p = 0.01$ and then solve $K$? Just assume that the poles becomes positive, all of them, then solve the $K$?

Comment: Use Routh Hurwitz method to solve it mathematically [http://pages.mtu.edu/~tbco/cm416/routh.html] OR use rlocus() function to find it by Matlab.

Comment: Plus, I'm afraid it is better to ask it in StackOverflow forum since this is a programming question.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar Thanks. But this is math too. You have given me a good answer :)

Comment: Glad I could help Daniel. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution now! Only for first order system!!!

Assume that we have a discrete and time continuous feedback system and we look at the poles:

$$0=Knum(s) + den(s)$$

$$0=Knum(z) + den(z)$$

For discrete system, we say $z_1 = 1, z_2 = -1$ and then we solve $K$.

For time continuous system. We say $s = 0$ and then we solve $K$.

Example:

Assume that we have a discrete system:

$$H(z) = \frac{0.09}{z-0.81}$$

And we want to find what gain $K$ gives a unstable system.

We pick up the formula:

$$0=Knum(z) + den(z) = K0.09 + z - 0.81$$

Then we insert $z_1 = 1$

$$\frac{-1+0.81}{0.09} = K = -2.11$$

And then $z_1 = -1$

$$\frac{1+0.81}{0.09} = K = 20.11$$

So my conclusion to this is that we cannot have a negative gain in our controller. The gain need to be positive. And our maximum gain is $20.11$.

Repeat this with a time continuous system transfer function.